# Camera intent doesn't show in intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

```
String chooseTitle = activity.getString(R.string.select_or_take_picture);

Intent getIntent = new Intent();
getIntent.setType("image/*");
getIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
PackageManager pm = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
for (ResolveInfo ri: pm.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)) {
  Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
  intents.add(intent);
}

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, photoUri);
for (ResolveInfo ri : pm.queryIntentActivities(cameraIntent, 0)) {
  Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
  intents.add(intent);
}

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, chooseTitle);
chooserIntent.putExtra(
    Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
    intents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {})
);
```

By doing this way, the chooser shows:

[image: Effect when I passed photoUri]

The camera intent doesn't show at all.

But if I change the line

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, photoUri);
```

to

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

It works just fine:

[image]

But the problem is, I really want to pass `photoUri`. How can I do with it?

I know a possible alternative is to write my own chooser dialog, but I do want to know if it's a bug in intent chooser, or if I don't use it correctly.

p.s. 
@dkarmazi, Here's how I generate Uri:

```
public Uri generatePhotoUri() {
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date());
  String imageFileName = "XXX_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
  File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
  File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
  return Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
}
```

Here's my `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_PHOTO:
      if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        break;
      }
      Uri source = data == null ?
          mPhotoUri : // take picture
          data.getData(); // choose from other app
      if (source == null) {
        break;
      }
      // TODO: do with source
      break;
  }
  //....
}
```

@dkarmazi, I've debugged it, and I make sure resultCode is `RESULT_CANCELED`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank [@dkarmazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342124/dkarmazi) very much for helping me debug this issue. It seems we haven't enough reputation to refine the answer together, so I'm posting the solution here. Later in our chat we find a probable cause, and after my experimenting, now it works. It's actually an issue how I gather `cameraIntent`s, so change this part of code

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, photoUri);
for (ResolveInfo ri : pm.queryIntentActivities(cameraIntent, 0)) {
  Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
  intents.add(intent);
}
```

to

```
final Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
for(ResolveInfo ri : pm.queryIntentActivities(cameraIntent, 0)) {
  final String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
  final Intent intent = new Intent(cameraIntent);
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(ri.activityInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
  intent.setPackage(packageName);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
  intents.add(intent);
}
```

Also need to change

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
PackageManager pm = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
for (ResolveInfo ri: pm.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)) {
  Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
  intents.add(intent);
}
```

to

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
PackageManager pm = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
for (ResolveInfo ri: pm.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)) {
  final String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
  final Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(ri.activityInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
  intent.setPackage(packageName);
  intents.add(intent);
}
```

I hate the boilerplate of it, but finally it works.

Comment: Don't forget to request permissions `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` , `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `CAMERA`

Answer (score 2):

I recently worked on the same problem and here is my solution:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
```

Then, once the user takes a picture, you should be able to access it by using the provided photoUri

Here is some documentation on [EXTRA_OUTPUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT) and you can also lookup ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE on the same page.

UPDATE on Intent Chooser:

```
// we create intent chooser by picking one of the intents
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.pick_action_string_for_user));
// then we add any additional intents
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { getIntent });
// chooserIntent is ready
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, requestCode);
```

Comment: I'm trying doing this way, but here's a another problem. How can I know if the user has taken the picture or if he just cancelled it. The resultCode is always `RESULT_CANCELED`!

Comment: Once the user takes the picture and it is successfully saved in the provided URI, in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data), resultCode should be RESULT_OK. One reason why you might be constantly getting RESULT_CANCELED is misformed photoUri. How do you actually generate this URI? Could you please show the code for generation of photoUri as well as onActivityResult?

Comment: I just added these codes. I find, even the picture is captured and saved, the resultCode is `RESULT_CANCELED`.

Comment: I know that you have mentioned that you debugged resultCode, but how do you start an activity for chooserIntent? Are you sure it has requestCode PICK_PHOTO passed to it?

Comment: the only other place I doubt is this: File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); 
Please try switching to File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "")

Comment: I just tried; it didn't work. I am sure I have passed `PICK_PHOTO`.

Comment: that's unfortunate. In this case I can only suggest you to simplify your code and temporarily get rid of chooserIntent and start cameraIntent directly and see if the issue persists and chooserIntent has something to do with this.

Comment: I just tried to get rid of chooserIntent; resultCode is `RESULT_OK`. Maybe it's an issue of intent chooser, or the way I use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78531/discussion-between-dkarmazi-and-misaka-10032).